# retrofit 2 post rxjava (login)

Tags: android, post, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I'm new using retrofit2 and rxjava, i was able to use GET to get information from api's but now, using POST for a login request is not working how is suposed too.

```
Application application = Application.get(mLoginView.getContext());
        Service Service = application.getmService();
        Log.i(TAG,""+username);
        Log.i(TAG,""+password);
        mSubscription = Service.login(username,password)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<User>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.i(TAG,"User: " + mUser.getHash());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i(TAG,"USERNAME DON'T EXIST");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(User user) {

                       // LoginPresenter.this.mUser = user;
                    }
                });
```

Service:

```
public interface Service {

String mUrl = "https://blabla.com/api/index.php/";  // TODO Change

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("user/login")
Observable<User> login(@Field(value="email",encoded=true)  String email, @Field(value="password",encoded = true) String password );
```

I enter a POST with username and pass from an existing user and return me a 404 page and not the hash im supposed to get.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that the URL is correct?

Comment: Yes that url in the code is a sample one but i'm sure the url is correct in the code

Comment: `username`  and `pass` are urlencoded by your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot this was here, I found a solutions months ago, and what i did was create a object UserCredentials to do the body request and a object to get the response.

```
@POST("user/login")
Observable<LoginResponse> login(@Body UserCredentials userCredentials);
```

Comment: how to call this ?

Comment: You mean the Observable? for that you need the rxjava lib in your gradle     compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'